# Cannot import from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I'm trying to import `CountVectorizer` from `sklearn` with the following line:

`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer`

- sklearn: 0.0
- scikit-learn: 0.23.2
- numpy: 1.19.2
- scipy: 1.5.2
- threadpoolctl: 2.1.0
- joblib: 0.17.0

Every time I try to run the code I receive the following error:

```
No name 'feature_extraction' in module 'sklearn' pylint(no-name-in-module)

Unable to import 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text' pylint(import-error)
```

If it matters I am running this in vscode on a Linux system inside of a VM. Also, I was able to run it earlier on the VM and it just stopped working for no apparent reason.

Comment: Are you using a venv? Can you update with output of: `pip list`, `python -c 'import sklearn;[print(x) for x in dir(sklearn)]'` ? Are you using `pylint`?

Comment: python3 -c 'import sklearn; [print(x) for x in dir(sklearn)]'
__SKLEARN_SETUP__
__all__

__builtins__
__cached__
__check_build
__doc__
__file__
__loader__
__name__
__package__
__path__
__spec__
__version__
_config
_distributor_init
base
clone
config_context
exceptions
get_config
logger
logging
os
set_config
setup_module
show_versions
sys
utils

Comment: I cannot print my full pip list as it's over the character limit, is there something specific you are looking for an I can put it here, also I think I'm using pylint, honestly don't know how to check

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why for some reason my vscode was saving my file as .pyc and it wouldn't recognize the library with pyc. If anyone else experiences this problem note my file still said py but auto-generated a **pycache** folder.

Answer (score 0):

because sklearn is deprecated
try this :

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scikit-learn is not being installed. please install it.

- open a new terminal.
- run this command:
  pip install scikit-learn